# Compiled OpenCV with OpenMP enabled, but application still runs on one core

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, openmp, opencv3.0

I noticed that my [Python](https://www.python.org) script using [OpenCV](http://opencv.org) is only using and maxing one of my cpu cores. I want to use the full potential of my cpu and not only 1/4th of it. As I researched, I found out that [OpenCV](http://opencv.org) is only using 1 core by default, and that to enable multi-threading, all I had to do was to enable [OpenMP](http://openmp.org/wp/) (`WITH_OPENMP=ON`) when compiling the library. So this is what I did, but when running my simple script, I see that it is still only using one core, greatly limiting the performances of my app.

Is there something else I need to do (perhaps modify my code) to enable the use of all the four cores of my [Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org)?

If not, maybe something went wrong with the installation process? The first time I installed [OpenCV](http://opencv.org), [OpenMP](http://openmp.org/wp/) wasn't enabled. Then after recompiling [OpenCV](http://opencv.org) with [OpenMP](http://openmp.org/wp/), all I did was `sudo make install` and `sudo ldconfig`. I did not uninstall the previous [OpenCV](http://opencv.org), guessing that installing the new [OpenCV](http://opencv.org) with [OpenMP](http://openmp.org/wp/) would override it.

Any insight is appreciated!!

Cheers

**EDIT:**

The goal of my script, is to capture the frames from a webcam and write them on the SD card simultanously.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time

CV_CAP_PROP_FPS = 5 #https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/e3ae36dcb3c1d523802f8642e5c3984db43637c4/modules/python/src2/defs

startTime = time.time()
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.div', fourcc, cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS), (640, 480))
nbOfFrames = 1

try:
    while(cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        if ret == True:
            out.write(frame)
            print(time.time() - startTime)
            print(nbOfFrames)
            nbOfFrames += 1
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    cap.release()
    out.release()
```

Comment: Did you see [this](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/28794/taking-advantage-of-multiprocessing-with-opencv-on-raspberry-pi-2)?

Comment: I did not see this question in my research before posting. But isn't the library suppose to handle multi-threading/multi-core for me?

Comment: Almost everything I find on multiprocessing involves C++. I do see a lot of stuff about TBB vs. OpenMP, though, so TBB might be something to look at. Some people seem to suggest that different functions use different services (TBB, OpenMP and some others) to handle the parallel processing. I notice on my Linux machine, my video-processing OpenCV Python script spreads the load across all four cores automatically. What OpenCV functions are you using? Do you mind sharing your code?

Comment: I have added my code in the question. I guess I will also try TBB instead of OpenMP.

Comment: By hard drive, do you mean SD card? I tried storing 100 bytes / second of streaming sensor data on my Pi's SD card once and it almost locked up my script after 10 seconds or so.

Comment: Yes, I do mean SD card. After my proof of concept, I will switch to a SSD. But I don't think it's part of the problem, it's just slower. Even without writing on the SD Card, I'm not even able to capture the full FPS of my webcam (which is 30). I capture about 22 fps and one core of my cpu is maxed to 100%, which is the reason why I want to use multiple cores.

Comment: I'm running your script now and my machine is automatically using all four cores. I actually just now updated OpenCV from 2.4 to 3.0 and I used [this page](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/) as a guide. The only thing I could think of trying with OpenCV is maybe install all the dependencies listed there? Otherwise, perhaps it's a Python setting somewhere.

Comment: I have followed the same instructions to install OpenCV 3.0. Did you try with OpenMP or with TBB? I'll look if there's a python setting.

Comment: I didn't do anything with either OpenMP or TBB. I just followed the instructions on that page, ran your script and saw that it uses all four cores on my machine. I don't know if there was anything special about those instructions or not.

Comment: That's weird. I ran the same exact instructions, and my script uses only one core. The instructions on this page compile OpenCV without OpenMP or TBB.  The reason why I wanted to add OpenMp or TBB was to allow multi-core usage, as it's what it says to do every where on the internet.

Comment: Installing OpenCV with OpenMP means some of the **OpenCV functions** will use multiple cores and execute faster (such as filters or image processing routines). The rest of the code (in your example, all of it) will be executed as you have programmed. Your code is a raw python code, just installing opencv wont make it magically parallel.

Comment: Ah! I see. So the `read` and `write` methods aren't optimized with OpenMP? Also I read that OpenCV didn't use OpenMP internally, but it uses TBB, so I was about to try that instead, but I guess I won't parallelize the code either right? So you're suggesting that I do thready manually instead? Thanks!

Comment: @imaluengo Why is his code using all of my cores when I run it but only one core when he runs the same code?

Comment: I am wondering about the same thing...

Comment: `read` and `write` might be using OpenMP (I don't know), but what is not using multitcores is the outer loop part `while ( ... )`. What you could do is to use `multiprocessing` python module to split frames between videoz. @Jason how do you monitor the core usage? Might be that some opemcv calls use all the cores, but the loop through frames is sequential.

Comment: [Here is my system monitor with his script running for a minute](http://i.imgur.com/GiWxshF.png) and [here is my system monitor without his script running for a minute](http://i.imgur.com/KnjqSWy.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [It turns out that only TBB is used internally to parallelize and
  optimize the code (and not OpenMP).](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.opencv/57404)
- Even with [TBB](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org), it seems like the [`read`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/videoio/doc/reading_and_writing_video.html#videocapture-read) and [`write`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/videoio/doc/reading_and_writing_video.html#videowriter-write) methods aren't parallelized internally, so it makes no difference.

Note that I might be wrong for each of those two points, as @Jason in the comments section of my question was able to run my script on all four cores (without even compiling with [TBB](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org) or OpenMP, which is weird).

So the only solution I found as of right now to use all four cores is to thread-ify my code manually. If I ever find an automatic solution (that is a solution that is implemented internally in [OpenCV](http://opencv.org)), I will update this answer.

If you are interested in building [OpenCV](http://opencv.org) with [TBB](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org), you can do it like this:

```
$ cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D BUILD_TBB=ON \
    -D WITH_TBB=ON \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

I get an error when compiling with [TBB](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org) for [OpenCV](http://opencv.org) 3.0, but there is a solution in this [GitHub ticket](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/5041) that works pretty well. Enjoy!

Comment: Opencv also has WITH_PTHREADS_PF flag. Maybe, the us of pthread is allowing the four core access for some modules which uses pthread. Pthread is also supposed to be faster.